# Extend existing Rails Path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering if there is a way to extend the existing path helpers that Rails created for my routes.

I have something like `/videos/view/:id` already and now I need to append a tag parameter to that link wherever it (from the current `params` collection).

The only solution I see right now is to go through all the views and change the call to the helper to look like this:

`view_videos_path(video, tag: params[:tag])`

Now obviously that's a bit of work and a much easier way to do this would be to just overwrite the existing path helper with something like this:

```
def view_videos_path(video, opts)
  view_videos_path(video, opts.merge(tag: params[:tag]))
end
```

Obviously putting this in a module would result in a endless recursion so I wonder if there is any best practice on how to do this.

Also, what do you think of the approach? I am not really sure if extending the helper like this is wise or not. But to me at the moment it looks reasonable.

Comment: I would personally change the helper name. Or you can call `super()` instead of the same method name directly

Comment: So I have to extend it or can I just create a regular `module` that simply overrides the method name?

Comment: Throw them in a helper module, you can include it into `ActionController` (so the paths are available in your controllers, too)

Comment: Go ahead and answer the question so I can mark it as accepted.. Worked perfectly .. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw them in a helper module and call `super`, you can also include it into `ApplicationController` so the paths are also available in your controllers:

```
# app/helpers/path_helpers.rb
module PathHelpers
  def view_videos_path(video, opts)
    super(video, opts.merge(tag: params[:tag]))
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  include PathHelpers # we could also use helper_method for each method
end
```